# how to limit the queryset of an inline model in django admin

Tags: python, django, inline, django-queryset, django-admin-filters

I have two models implemented like

```
class A(models.Model):
    a_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    b_tag = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)             # stores username
```

Now I define an `A` admin and register it with `B` as a subclass to `TabularInline`. I wonder if it is possible somehow to filter the list of `B` objects before the inline formset is rendered, so not all `B` objects related to `A` get into the formset, only ones whose `user` parameter matches the currently logged in user shows up!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use the `get_queryset` method:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset

Should look like:

```
class BAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    ...

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(BAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(user=request.user)
```

Comment: thanks a bunch .It worked like a charm!  . If i could trouble you for one more thing , Why does our overridden function call its superclass TabularInline.

Comment: The superclass call gets the initial queryset that filters on the A model.

Comment: In general, this is a great method overall for filtering TabularInline and StackedInline.